# How to add login Items by code to mountain lion osx

Tags: authentication, osx-mountain-lion

I want to add login items programmatically in Mountain Lion (10.8).

Until now I was able to add login items by editing this plist:

```
/Users/test/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist
```

and adding items (path,name,hide) to `AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary` dictionary
in the OS doesn't work anymore. Items that are added to this dictionary are not launched on login. I see that the login items are saved in a file called: `com.apple.loginitems.plist`

but I don't understand how to add an item to this file. I tried to add the item to `CustomListItems` dictionary with parameters like name,path, hide but they were not launched on login.

Does anyone know how can I add from code login item?

Comment: The answer seems to be documented at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-BAJJBJEG but we have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to start your program automatically when your user logs in.

In *older* versions of *OS X*, it was possible to add login items manually by editing *loginwindow.plist*. [Apple deprecated this approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-BAJJBJEG) when they added *LaunchAgent* and *LaunchDaemon* functionality to the OS.

Since you are using *Mountain Lion*, the correct way to have a program launch is to create a **launchagent** for it. This is a *.plist* file that you can use to tell OS X to **a)** perform some action (e.g.: launch */some/program.app*) when **b)** a specific event occurs (e.g.: logging in, logging out, etc)

You will find Apple's official document on creation of *LaunchAgents* [over here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a great tutorial on the modern way of doing things: [The launch at login sandbox project](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/)

It starts with a paragraph buried in the [App Sandbox design guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW3):

> **Creating a Login Item for Your App**
>
> To create a login item for your sandboxed app, use the SMLoginItemSetEnabled function (declared in ServiceManagement/SMLoginItem.h) as described in “Adding Login Items Using the Service Management Framework” in Daemons and Services Programming Guide.
>
> (With App Sandbox, you cannot create a login item using functions in the LSSharedFileList.h header file. For example, you cannot use the function LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL. Nor can you manipulate the state of launch services, such as by using the function LSRegisterURL.)

And rolls from there...